# What would be the best way to do pathfinding on a random object that rotates

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to do pathfinding on a rotating "planet", similar like the enemies do in mario galaxy, except the planets are rotating. What would be the best way to do it? The planets come in different forms, and it is necessary that I place the waypoint with code. That is because I need to do it with code for my assignment and also I want to make an object pool of waypoints that get placed on the planet the player is currently on.

So is A* the best way to go? I was thinking about the technique I should use and I thought of placing every waypoint on a vertex of the model. But some models can get pretty high in vertices, so isn't that really heavy if I have that many waypoint and then use them for path finding?

Or is there a better way of doing it? I was thinking can't you do it based on the uv's of the planet? The only thing is that the uv's have cuts so how can I tell the enemy to also check the cuts of the uv's for a shorter path?

Comment: Ok, if you are on planet surface and you need a simple pathfinding system to move around why you don't use unity build in navigation system? The rotation of planets doesn't metter if you are "into" the planet and not in same space and need to avoid or find them... take a look at unity navigation lessons or be more specific illustrating your scenery... https://unity3d.com/pt/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/navigation/navigation-overview?playlist=17105

Comment: I worked on rapid exploring random trees (you can search as RRT path finding) in my internship. Best thing is it works great in 3d space. Sadly I would share my project but sadly I couldnt find it.  You can give it a try.

Comment: The surface of a planet would still essentially be a 2d space

Answer (score 0):

Best way to animate planets will be to download leanTween or some similar asset and make animation by curve path + rotation.